# Wireless network testing software

Tags: wireless, testing

I want to be able to check the speeds / throughput on my LAN, check for signal strength, interference, dead spots etc. How do I do that?

I'm having some issues with my wireless, particularly with an Iphone / Ipad and I want to find out why.
I have Windows & Linux machines available.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic for this forum.

Comment: I think it's a valid question but I reworded it anyways.

Comment: I gave an answer to the reworded question. Also, if this is for home networking, that, too, is off-topic for this forum.

Comment: This is silly. What difference does it make?

Comment: The community has decided that is a site for professional networking. Certain topics are not allowed in order to maintain the professional level of this forum. Things like this can be asked on Super User, but specific recommendations are probably not allowed there either. Recommendations are primarily opinion-based and can start flame wars.

Comment: What exactly is not professional about my question? Also, saying "no recommendations" is like saying "no tool naming" - I ask how do you do X and you say with tools and software - Duh, I though I had to use voodoo...

Comment: You can ask questions about specific tools, but recommending one is off-topic. Please read all about it in the Help Center. This was a community decision, not mine personally, so asking me why the decision was made is not productive. There are links for off-topic questions that justify the reasons for making some questions off-topic.

Comment: See this link for specifics: http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255/recommendations-and-polls

Comment: again, is this home netorking? Please cask on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

1. useful tool can help you to make good wireless survey is wifi analyzer on the android phones. its can work on both ranges 2.4 and 5 GHZ 
   [image: wifi analyzer]

you can use it to figure out channel utility and it DPI and it can help in find the places of the APs as well

2. on PC insider could be one of the best wireless survey tools 
   [image: insider]

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a wireless tester or get some software for your computer(s) or smartphone to check for signal strength, interference, dead spots etc.

LAN throughput can be checked from PC to PC with the proper software.

Product recommendations are specifically off-topic for this forum.  See the help site.

> **Off-topic: Product or Resource Recommendations**
>
> Requests for product recommendations, resource recommendations, or
>   polls are off-topic.
>
> However, polls and recommendations are welcome in the Network
>   Engineering Recommendations Chat Room.